# Get All Hyperlinks in web application

Tags: hyperlink

We have a scenario to address. Our SharePoint (On-Premise) web application has 1 site collection. Which has multiple sites. In these sites at number of places an external application (www.abc.com) links are placed through Summary Link web part. 
Now the external application URL has changed (www.xyz.com) . And we have to update all Hyperlinks to have new URL.

Having a feeling this scenario is very practical i.e. could be happening for many Intranet applications which have external applications. Thus, should be there are way to achieve this.

Looking for all site pages and all links is not a practical task. Thus, looking for way to get a matrix generated having Page URL | Link Title | Link URL.

Not able to find any script / code / PS.

got this link. but again it is page specific
[get all hyperlinks from page content in sharepoint 2010 using powershell or object model](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b5cb3ce9-63b3-44ce-a172-e0c2c55c25d0/get-all-hyperlinks-from-page-content-in-sharepoint-2010-using-powershell-or-object-model?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

Comment: May be outbound rule in IIS?

Comment: Any one any ideas...?