# Get list of all hyperlink targets within site

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, hyperlink

On one of my sites, some of the links are to an "external" web site (actually internal but not part of, or a subsite of, this one). I need to change all of those, but I can't see any way to find them that's better than manually going through every single page, and every link on every page.

This question may be a duplicate of:
[Get All Hyperlinks in web application](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/242619/get-all-hyperlinks-in-web-application)

However, that question was never answered, so ....

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Source:** [Find and Replace URL Links from Hyperlink Columns in SharePoint](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/10/find-and-replace-links-in-hyperlink-columns-powershell.html?m=1)

You can use the below PowerShell code :

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

 

Function Replace-LinkFields($WebURL, $OldLinkURL, $OldLinkTitle, $NewLinkURL, $NewLinkTitle)

{

    #Get the Web

    $Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL

 

    #Get all lists - Exclude System lists

    $ListCollection = $web.lists | Where-Object  { ($_.hidden -eq $false) -and ($_.IsSiteAssetsLibrary -eq $false) -and ($_.Author.LoginName -ne "SHAREPOINT\system") }

  

    #Iterate through each list

    foreach ($List in $ListCollection)

    {

        #find all HyperLink fields in list

        $HyperlinkFields = @()

        foreach ($field in $list.Fields)

        {

            if ($field.TypeAsString -eq "URL")

            {

                $HyperlinkFields = $HyperlinkFields + $field.Title     

            }

        }   

        write-host "Processing list at: $($web.url)/$($list.RootFolder.Url)"

 

        #Process all hyperlink fields found

         

        #Proceed with next list if Hyperlink field is not found in the list

        if($HyperlinkFields.Count -eq 0) { continue }

 

        foreach ($Item in $List.Items)

        {

            #Iterate through HyperLink fields

            foreach ($field in $HyperlinkFields)

            {

                #Get field value

                $FieldValue = $item[$field]

                #Skip nulls

                if($FieldValue -ne $null)

                {

                    # Check for OldLinkURL or OldLinkTitle

                    if( ($FieldValue.contains($OldLinkURL)) -or ($FieldValue.contains($OldLinkTitle)) )

                    {            

                        #Replace the OLD URL with New URL

                        $Item[$field] = ($item[$field] -Replace $OldLinkURL,$NewLinkURL)

                        #Replace OLD link title with new link title

                        $Item[$field] = ($item[$field] -Replace $OldLinkTitle,$NewLinkTitle)

 

                        $Item.update()

                        Write-host "Found and replaced a old link item at: $($web.Url)/$($list.RootFolder.Url) - Item id: $($item.id)"     

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }  

}
```

**Call the function to Replace Links in lists**

```
Replace-LinkFields "http://Intranet.crescent.com/" "http://portal.crescent.com"  "Crescent Intranet"
```

Note:

- The above code replacing the old link to a new link, so if you just want to get details of links then you can comment on the link update code.